# How to cast a variable to custom Class in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this variable that I want to cast to custom class

```
obj = {'model': 'User'}
```

User is a Aqlalchemy model name.

I want something like this:

```
user = User()
```

and of course this wouldn't work:

```
use = obj['model']()
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing `obj = {'model': User}`?

Comment: Yes, actually, I'm getting a json from other service, it would be result of service which is String so can not be object type User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your class in a dictionary and then by your `json` input you can convert `json` to a dictionary from `model` to `class`:

```python
import json

class User:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "User Class"

class Admin:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Admin Class"

models= {"User": User, "Admin": Admin}

jsonStr = '{"model1":"User","model2":"Admin"}'
obj = json.loads(jsonStr)

convertedObj = {k:models[v] for k,v in obj.items()}

print(convertedObj["model1"]())
print(convertedObj["model2"]())
```

The output will be:

```
User Class
Admin Class
```